# Yii 2 - How to set connection in DB Query for multi database

Tags: yii2

How to set db connection in yii-db-query?

I have a **3 database connection**:

> db, db2 and db3

When I used this default **Query**:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('trans_journal')
            ->all();
```

It will **return an** **error**. The **trans_journal** is not **found**, because the **trans_journal** is from the **db2 connection**.

And when I used this **Query**:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select('*')
            ->from('trans_journal')
            ->all(\Yii::$app->db2);
```

The query will be successfully generated but the problem is it will **return an array**.

Is there another way to solved this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using an active record model, in your model you can redefine properly the getDB function for each model:

```
  // Model1 

  public function getDb() {
      return Yii::$app->db1;
  }

  //Model 2
  public function getDb() {
      return Yii::$app->db2;
  }
```

If you are using command you can set the db in use just in createCommand call

```
// To get from db1
Yii::$app->db1->createCommand(
          (new \yii\db\Query)->select('col1, col2, ... ')->
                          from('your_table_db1'))->queryAll();

// To get from db2
Yii::$app->db2->createCommand(
            (new \yii\db\Query)->select('col1, col2, ... ')->
                          from('your_table_db2')->queryAll();
```

The all()  method executes the query and returns all results as an array.

You can iterate over the result for get each model  eg:

```
 $results =  Yii::$app->db1->createCommand(
          (new \yii\db\Query)->select('col1, col2, ... ')->
                          from('your_table_db1'))->queryAll();

foreach($results as $key => $value ){
    echo $value->col1;
    // or $value['col1];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
 ->select('*')
 ->from('trans_journal')
 ->all();

 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'db' => Yii::$app->get('db2'),
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
```